# Centering a background-image within div and keep proportions when scaling

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

**EDIT:** Sorry, I realise it wasn't so clear, I'll try to clarify.

What I searching for is something that helps me to "zoom"/"scale" my background-image within the div when adjusting the height (not the width) of the browser window. (See attached image)

So far I've only managed to get the image to crop but still being centered using the code below.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Image of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMbu.jpg

```css
.wrap {
  height: 50%
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1020px;
  background:url('https://placebear.com/2040/866') no-repeat;
  width:2040px;
  height:866px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: use percentage for dimension instead of px?

Comment: When you say you want the height to change according to the browser window what do you mean? When the width changes or the height? How do you want the image to relate to the height or width of the browser?

Comment: Sorry I realise it wasn't so clear. What I searching for is something that helps me to "zoom"/"scale" my background-image within the div when adjusting the height (not the width) of the browser window.

Comment: I'm still not 100% about what you want to achieve here, but you can use `vh` to adjust the height of the container relative to the browser height.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your patience. How do you mean vh? Where shall I put it? Did you see this picture: http://imgur.com/a/zJgF4

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are describing.

You can use `background-size: cover;` so that the image always fills the container.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

This will at least scale the image to the correct proportions. Then you can scale the container how you want.

You can use `vh` units of measurement to control the height of the image container based on the height of the browser window.

https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

```css
.wrap {
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://placebear.com/2040/866') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! We're almost there :)  But I need the image to "scale"/"zoom" within the wrap when adjusting the browser height?